# Creating a canonical question when 5 votes are needed to close

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I am trying to close old questions as duplicates of the most suitable version I could find for a canonical, namely this question:

- [Parse an AWS CloudFormation template with the PyYAML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914422/parse-an-aws-cloudformation-template-with-a-yaml-library)

I chose that one as it had the best question and answer IMO. I also then added an answer of my own there.

In the mean time I identified a few others that I consider to be exact duplicates of it:

- [could not determine a constructor for the tag '!GetAtt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786412/could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag-getatt)
- [could not determine a constructor for the tag '!REF'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878475/could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag-ref#comment97432841_54878475)

This one is also very similar but I judged it to be not quite identical:

- [How to Parse YAML Using PyYAML if there are '!' within the YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240554/how-to-parse-yaml-using-pyyaml-if-there-are-within-the-yaml)

**Considering I need 5 close votes to complete these closes, what should I do?**

I note that the probability of 5 other people cleaning up in this same tag is surely close to zero. Should I just cast my vote and leave it at that? Have I already taken too much initiative to get this far? Is there another process to follow?

Comment: Consider asking the SO close vote reviewers, see https://socvr.org/ Or find another relevant [chat room with people covering the tag's expertise area](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to see if people there agree and can help out.

Comment: In this case, I'm actually not so certain those two posts should be closed as duplicates; there is no indication that those have anything to do with using Python to parse the YAML documents.

Comment: Yeah, but you can tell from the error messages that the OPs are using the PyYAML library.

Comment: Are you 100% certain? Can't there be other implementations that output that error?

Comment: I can't produce that message using any other library. I could be wrong.

Comment: The first one, with `yaml.constructor.ConstructorError` in the error message is *probably* Python, sure, given the dotted path and layout. The second post, however, has formatted the output quite differently.

Comment: I'll double-check. I think PyYAML is making "could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Ref'" and then custom code around that is making the rest.

Comment: But the first post is about passing the YAML data to a build agent. That build agent may well be implemented in Python but I see no indication that it is within the control of the OP to alter its source code. The other post talks about *but when I try to deploy this*, so again, probably using 3rd party tools, not their own code.

Comment: In other words: the duplicate would not help either post, not unless they can alter the tools that they are using. Unless you have evidence otherwise, these are not duplicates. I don't know enough about the AWS Cloudformation tooling and deployment configuration to be able to say that it isn't the file format that's at fault, or if a package is missing, or a version indicator that'd tell the tools to enable the multi_constructor config.

Comment: Yes fair enough. I believe the error is emitted [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/e471e86bf6dabdad45a1438c20a4a5c033eb9034/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L419) and of course it could be that the OP needs to edit the build agent source. Happy to just not close them if that's the consensus.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for you advice. I've retracted the close vote on both.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. I'm pretty sure these errors are emitted by tooling the OPs have no control over. So either their config is incorrect, or their tooling outdated, or something else is wrong, but knowing how to configure a Python library to make the syntax work is not going to help them.

Comment: Well there's no information in the questions about their tooling. :)

Comment: So the questions can perhaps be closed for other reasons. I see plenty of comments and even a few deleted non-answers that are asking for more details.

Comment: I'm still 99% sure, from my knowledge of possible tooling options etc, that the question I linked would help the OPs get to a solution. But happy to defer to your judgement.

Comment: Ok, I've added comments instead suggesting they "may" be duplicates, and I note you've closed them anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, one other thing: just interested in the process point: Isn't closing as dupes better in this particular situation given that people searching on Google are most likely to be there as a result of the PyYAML error? If they were brand new questions, sure. I would just ask for more info.

Comment: It's a judgment call. In this case, with zero code and only the yaml snippets, it's probably better to just close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overall, cleaning up dupes is a good thing, but as you noticed, it is hard to do for a single person.

What I would do here is to hunt down one or several [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) "gold badgers". That is, users with a gold badge in the Python tag, who can dupe hammer posts themselves. Explain the situation to them and they can help, and also review what you have done for second opinion.

It might be easiest to do this live over chat, so maybe go looking for Python gold badgers in one of the SO chats. Try the Python chat room or "SO close vote review" chat room. In case you find no gold badgers, you might at least find enough Python users to round up the needed votes.